# CSS not working in HTML file

Tags: html, css

It has been working... But I don't know why it is not working anymore. I am using Django to set up a local server (?) and I use MySQL for something else. The .css file is into a folder where the .html file is located, and like I said before it has been working.

My code inside the **head**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

{% load static %}

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JFP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" >
</head>

<body>

<div class="header"> 
...
```

My **.css** is not worth mentioning, is it?

Comment: Please include your main.css, since the possibility is high that the error is within that file.

Comment: check your console on the browser to see if you are getting a resource not found error

Comment: Is `bootstrap.css` being loaded ?

Comment: Some bootstrap functions are working well, so I think bootstrap is loader. @Rob1NN: what doe you meannby include main.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem was: indeed a wrong reference to my **.css** file. I was scrolling in my Terminal to some MySQL command from the moment there was not yet an 404 fault. It had to be:

```
/static/main.css
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

If the CSS file is in External server the code is

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@import url(stile.css);
</style>
</head>
<body>[...]
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Likely an error in the CSS file. Run it through a validation checker. Also ensure you are referencing the correct elements within that css file.

And as others has said, check the browser console for errors loading either resources.